# How databases are saved

Tags: database, storage, javadb

I am trying to implement databases into my Java applications, but before I am able to do that, I need to know: where will the data be stored? Will a person that is using my program be able to fully use it ON ANY COMPUTER? Will there be anything external (a maintenance program, routine cleaning, etc.) that will destroy the database? I know that, if you are using JavaDB (which I am), you have to establish a connection. Where does this connection go?

Answer (score 0):

A Derby database (what I am using) stores the database on the hard disk, in the same directory as the program that is running it, by default. You can, however, control where the database is being stored by specifying a pathname. Actually, according to this, http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop12.html#HDRSII-DEVELOP-13018 , the database saves to the system directory by default. If you don't specify where this is (with `derby.system.home`), it assumes `systemDirectory == currentDirectory` or more specifically, the directory you are running the program from.